# deserialize json at runtime with any class

Tags: serialization, dynamic, jackson, runtime

I have a Kafka consumer library which consumes a byte array. My upstream will always publish a JSON string into bytes. Upon consuming, and converting to string, I need to be able to deserialize this into a class which is going to be different for different consumers.

Here is how I am trying to deserialise

```
public class MessageUtil<T> {

    public T deserializeByStringConversion(final byte[] message) throws Exception {
        String json = IOUtils.toString(message);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<T>() {});
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to invoke this

```
MessageUtil<MyClass> messageUtil;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyClass() throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = messageUtil.deserializeByStringConversion(IOUtils.toByteArray(request));
        Assert.assertNotNull(myClass);
    }
```

This throws the following exception -

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast
> to com.a.b.c.d.MyClass

I have multiple consumers which work on different classes, where MyClass will be different. How can I write this deserialiser to work on a generic type?

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the type info as the deserializeByStringConversion signature, for example.

```
public class MessageUtil<T> {

    public T deserializeByStringConversion(final byte[] message, TypeReference<T> valueTypeRef) throws Exception {
        String json = IOUtils.toString(message);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, valueTypeRef);
    }
}
```

```
    @Test
    public void testMyClass() throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = messageUtil.deserializeByStringConversion(IOUtils.toByteArray(request), new TypeReference<MyClass>() {});
        Assert.assertNotNull(myClass);
    }
```